What's the difference between className and classList.value?
Before you mark this answer as duplicate, I'm talking about "classList.value", not "classList".
What are the differences between:
element.className = 'main';
element.classList.value = 'main';

They can both "get and set the value of the class attribute of a specified element" (MDN's description of what className does).
I noticed the difference in performance seems very little (run it multiple times).
So, is there a difference?
I'm asking partially for curiousity, but also because everywhere I look it seems "className" is favoured - according to MDN's Browser compatibility it did come before classList.value.
.className is often recommended for setting the class list or clearing it. But.classList is also recommended when toggling, adding, removing. So, why not use .classList.value for consistency?

These are essentially the same; except that the classList itself is a space-delimited string and allows for easy toggling of individual classes.

What differences do you expect? Do you have a problem that you are trying to solve where you think the difference might matter? Or are you just curious why both exist?

@mykaf As I said at the start of the question, I'm talking about classList.value, not classList.

@Bergi Sorry, I don't actually know how I posted the question. It was sent early, before I could explain things. And then, just before I was about to post the full question, I realised I had some how already posted this one... Anyways, I've edited this question with the answers you just asked.

"So, why not use .classList.value for consistency?" it's longer and has no real value for it? I think you expect some grand revelation instead of just...healthy laziness.

@VLAZ If .classList.value and .className are the same, then they both have no value. Also, "longer" simply doesn't matter, just copy and paste like you already do. I'd rather have consistency: classList.add, classList.toggle, classList.value, classList.remove, classList.contains, classList.replace, not to mention, using className prevents you from copying and pasting, it's annoying since you actually have to type it out. I'm not looking for a grand revelation, I'm just checking if there was an actual reason, but if not, then there's not, the answer is "no".

@Tigerrrrr ""longer" simply doesn't matter, just copy and paste like you already do" - not everyone programs only by copy'n'paste. I write new programs that I type out, and at best use autocompletion where one property is quicker than two properties. "using className prevents you from copying and pasting" - not sure what you mean by that.

I also just type and use autocomplete. classList.value is two autocmpletes. It's longer. Finding what to copy would take me more time than either option, since it takes more than a single second.

I understand what you were asking; I'm pointing out that classList.value is part of classList, but essentially they do the same thing, while classList itself has some benefits.


everywhere I look it seems .className is favoured

Sure. It's shorter, simpler, faster, and - as you noted - supported by more (older) browsers. So there's hardly any reason to use .classList.value.

But .classList is also recommended when toggling, adding, removing. So, why not use .classList.value for consistency?

The class list is used when interacting with (toggling/adding/removing) individual classes. It is much easier to use for that than doing string manipulation on .className, like in olden times when .classList was not yet available.
It is rare in general to replace the whole list. You might do it to remove all class names, but when working with a classList of individual classes then you should really only operate on those that your piece of code is responsible for. In that case you won't use .value, so there's no consistency to achieve. The property mainly exists for completeness of the interface, and for other usages of DOMTokenLists.
If you really exercise complete control over the whole list, and want to manipulate it all at once, then again .className is simpler and shorter.

There is exactly one benefit classList.value has. It's dubious when that'd be appropriate (so far, I've had zero uses) but here it goes: you can assign classList to a variable like x = el.classList (or pass it as parameter) an then you'd be able to use x.value to read or assign to it. You can't do the same with classList. With that said, it's extremely rare I'd need either. As the answer points out - usually you want to interact with an individual class (through classList) or, at most, wipe all classes (where .className = "" is easier).

@VLAZ Yes, good point, you can share (store, …) the class list object if you don't want the capabilites of the whole dom element. But other than introducing such restriction (or just clarity), I don't think it's much simpler. And still, the capability to use cl.value = "" is not different than the capability to cl.remove(...cl).

As I said - needing to pass around classList itself it has never come up for me.  It's extremely rare I have to interact with classes and when I do, I usually would want the element anyway.

Thanks for your answer! Personally, I find most of the time I use className to set the class list back to 0 classes, and then I might classList.add() more later on, so I think I'll start just using classList.value for that role instead for consistency. Also, I'd like to add a couple points: .className isn't faster and not simpler either. Support for old browsers - well both of them support "old browsers", but .className can support even older browsers. like v1 of FireFox and Safari versus v47 and v10 (we're currently on v126 and v17.5) respectively.
